# Replacing spaces in a complex string in JS

Tags: javascript, string, replace, replaceall

```
var generated_pubkey = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- xjMEY17rXBY86d3b e2e70cf35bc6b9490 0a0e76a27a9fc15e769 d674e3a9ce7d6bad5== =G4p6 -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- "
```

I want to replace the space that comes after "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----" with \n\n and replace all other spaces with 1 \n while keeping the spaces between the wording “ -----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----” without any replacement also keeping “END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK”

So the result becomes:

```
"-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\n\nxjMEY17rXBY86d3b\ne2e70cf35bc6b9490\n0a0e76a27a9fc15e769\nd674e3a9ce7d6bad5==\n=G4p6\n-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----\n"
```

Note: The public key generated will be random.The double \n\n will always be installed after the first “BLOCK-----“ as shown above, the public key string will always end with a space that should be replaced with a single \n while other spaces will be replaced with single \n.

I have already tried:

```
generated_pubkey.replaceAll(" ", "\n")
```

But that replaced even the spacing between the wording of BEGIN PGP etc and END PGP etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First can replace `'-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- '` (one space) with `'-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----  '` (two spaces ) using `.replace()`.

Then, all you need to do is create a simple function to toggle between new lines or spaces depending on whether or not it is between two `-----`s

```js
function replaceSpaces(str) {
  let ret = "";
  let isOn = true;
  for (const tok of str.split(' ')) {
    if (tok.includes('-----')) isOn = !isOn;
    if (isOn) ret += tok + '\n';
    else ret += tok + ' ';
  }
  return ret;
}

let generated_pubkey = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- xjMEY17rXBY86d3b e2e70cf35bc6b9490 0a0e76a27a9fc15e769 d674e3a9ce7d6bad5== =G4p6 -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- ";
generated_pubkey = generated_pubkey.replace('-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- ', '-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----  ')
const new_pubkey = replaceSpaces(generated_pubkey);

console.log(new_pubkey);
```

Answer (score 0):

if there are signs you don't want to replace, you could set it to a character which doesn't appear and use replaceAll after that, reset the character from above, like:

```
let generated_pubkey = "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- xjMEY17rXBY86d3b e2e70cf35bc6b9490 0a0e76a27a9fc15e769 d674e3a9ce7d6bad5== =G4p6 -----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- ";

let temp = generated_pubkey.replaceAll("-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- ", "-----BEGIN~PGP~PUBLIC~~KEY~BLOCK-----\n\n");
temp = temp.replaceAll("-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----", "-----END~PGP~PUBLIC~KEY~BLOCK-----");
temp = temp.replaceAll(" ", "\n");

temp = temp.replaceAll("~", " ");
generated_pubkey = temp;
```